# Set compiled matlab GUI folder

Tags: matlab, directory, matlab-guide

I have a Matlab GUI (I compile it) that in order to load a file I press a button that uses this line

```
[file, folder] = uigetfile({'*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp','All Image Files'},' Select image');
```

If I press the button again it opens the folder where the software is installed. How can I change it that it will remember and open the last folder I used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation for [`uigetfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html), you can specify an optional third input argument, `DefaultName`:

> `[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile(FilterSpec,DialogTitle,DefaultName)` displays a dialog box
>   in which the file name specified by `DefaultName` appears in the File
>   name field. `DefaultName` can also be a path or a path/filename. In
>   this case, `uigetfile` opens the dialog box in the folder specified by
>   the path. You can use `.`,`..`,`\`, or `/` in the `DefaultName`
>   argument. To specify a folder name, make the last character of
>   `DefaultName` either `\` or `/`. If the specified path does not exist,
>   `uigetfile` opens the dialog box in the current folder.

You can store the last opened folder to your GUI and access it when the button callback is fired.

For example:

```
function testgui
h.f = figure('MenuBar', 'none', 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'ToolBar', 'none');
h.b = uicontrol('Parent', h.f, 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'Units', 'Normalized', ...
                'Position', [0.1 0.3 0.8 0.4], 'String', 'Pick a file');
h.l = uicontrol('Parent', h.f, 'Style', 'text', 'Units', 'Normalized', ...
                'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.8 0.1], 'String', '');
setappdata(h.f, 'lastfolder', '');
h.l.String = sprintf('Last Directory: %s', '');

h.b.Callback = @(o, e) abutton(h);
end

function abutton(h)
lastfolder = getappdata(h.f, 'lastfolder');
[file, folder] = uigetfile({'*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp','All Image Files'},' Select image', lastfolder);

if folder ~= 0
    setappdata(h.f, 'lastfolder', folder);
    h.l.String = sprintf('Last Directory: %s', folder);
end    
end
```

[image: yay]

Note that this approach resets to your current directory when the GUI is closed and reopened.

Comment: Thanks it works great and works very well. How can I add the function testgui content to my OpeningFcn?

Comment: You only need `setappdata` in your `OpeningFcn`.

Comment: I got this error: Undefined variable "h" or class "h.f".
Error in V1ba>V1ba_OpeningFcn (line 75)
setappdata(h.f, 'lastfolder', '');
Error in gui_mainfcn (line 220)
    feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn, gui_hFigure, [], guidata(gui_hFigure), varargin{:});
Error in V1ba (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});  what shell I fix?

Comment: Use the correct handle to your GUI window from your `handles` structure.

Comment: I am using GUIDE and not a Programmatic UI. Therefore I can do not find information on what I should replace the h.f in setappdata(h.f, 'lastfolder', '') that should be in the OpeningFcn?

Answer (score 0):

The `folder` output from `uigetfile` is the path that was selected.  Use this as the input to the next call to `uigetfile`

```
[file, folder] = uigetfile({'*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp','All Image Files';},...
            'Select Image', folder);
```

This is an example from `doc uiputfile` but it works with `uigetfile` as well.

Comment: @user2916044 If you want it to remember between sessions of running the GUI then you need to `save` it.  When the GUI opens, `load` it.